# Запретить отправку комментариев через ВК на сайте до получения определенных прав

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Хочу поставить на сайт комментарии ВК, но разрешить их отправку только после того, как пользователь авторизуется на сайте через VK.Auth.login и предоставит нужные мне права. Я понимаю, что могу по умолчанию не выводить блок с комментариями и вывести его только после получения нужных прав от пользователя, но я хочу, чтобы комменты были видны, просто не отправлялись. Также я понимаю, что могу скрыть кнопку "Отправить" и поле для ввода до получения этих прав, или сделать что-нибудь через onclick вместо отправки комментария, но от продвинутых пользователей и/или ботов это не защитит, и они все равно смогут отправлять комментарии, формируя запрос безо всякой кнопки. Возможно ли полноценно запретить отправлять комментарии через виджет ВК до получения определенных прав, но при этом позволить читать комментарии?